# How do I open a .apk google example?

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok so I want to learn android push notifications. I found at android to use the C2DM service.
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Great they even give me an example. http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/downloads/list

My problem is I don't know what to do with the file after I download it. :P
It is an .apk file.  So how do I open it in eclipse to learn from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An apk is an android install app thingy you run it on your phone. To edit search android code examples and select the first one select what you want to edit dowbload the manifest and the other files and edit them in eclipse. Have you ever tried opening a .exe in notepad it does not work so well because it is already compiled same (i think) with the. Apk also make sure you have the android plugib for exlipse. Sorry for the strange language I am a delvoper who forgets the name of everything. And the grammer i am only 13.

Comment: hehe I got this a long time ago however I seem to have forgotten to get back to this thread and answer it.  I am sorry for this and thank you for bringing me back here.

Answer (score 0):

Rename it to `.zip` and you can open it with your favorite zip unarchiving program.

Comment: i get nothing or I get all the squares and funky symbols

Comment: Well, it looks like building the APK does something to the XML files.  If you want to look at the code, just look at the code: http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FJumpNoteAndroid

Comment: XML files are converted to a binary format for performance reasons when the APK is built.